# Rotation and adjustment on all devices

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, css, media-queries

The problem I have is this: I'm making an application using HTML5, JavaScript and CSS3. My idea is that it can be used from any computer and tablet (possibly after will also include smartphones) and it has to fit any size. I tried using "media queries" but when I rotate the device (from horizontal to vertical or vice versa) does not fit properly. I tried using this function but I did not end up working:

```
/*SCRIPT PARA TAMANIO DE LA VENTANA*/ 
    window.onload=function() 
    {    
        dameElTamanioDePantalla(); 
    }

    function dameElTamanioDePantalla () 
    {
        setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0,1); }, 10); 
        var alto = document.height; 
        var ancho = document.width; 
        document.getElementById('barraSuperior').style.width = "100%"; 
        document.getElementById('barraSuperior').style.height = ((alto*0.05).toString()).concat("px"); 
        document.getElementById('barraInferior').style.width = "100%"; 
        document.getElementById('barraInferior').style.height = ((alto*0.05).toString()).concat("px"); 
        document.getElementById('contenidoPrincipal').style.width = "95%"; 
        document.getElementById('contenidoPrincipal').style.height = ((alto*0.9).toString()).concat("px");
    }

    /*SCRIPT QUE DETECTA Y CAMBIA EL MEDIA QUERY SI CAMBIA DE LANDSCAPE A PORTRAIT*/

    detectOrientation();
window.onorientationchange = detectOrientation;
function detectOrientation(){
    if(typeof window.onorientationchange != 'undefined'){
        if ( orientation == 0 ) {
             //Do Something In Portrait Mode
            dameElTamanioDePantalla();
        }
        else if ( orientation == 90 ) {
             //Do Something In Landscape Mode
            dameElTamanioDePantalla();
        }
        else if ( orientation == -90 ) {
             //Do Something In Landscape Mode
            dameElTamanioDePantalla();
        }
        else if ( orientation == 180 ) {
             //Do Something In Landscape Mode
            dameElTamanioDePantalla();
        }
    }
}
```